# Home Server multisite htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns, centos, dyndns

I have a home server with CENTOS.

```
- public 
   - www
     - SITE1
     - SITE2
     - SITE3
     - SITE4
     - .htaccess
```

With dyndns i visualize my sites.

Now I have 4 domain: site.com, site.org, site.net, site.biz.

Now changing dns CNAME all my site point to my home server.

I want that when I am in site.com the root is SITE1, when I'm in site.org is SITE2,etc...

I try with htaccess, for the first site it work

```
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^$ /SITE1/ [L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /SITE1/$1

   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^SITE1/(.*[^/])$ http:// site.com/$1/ [R=301]
```

Comment: Why don't you use a VirtualHost configuration ? Is it an Apache server and have you access to its configuration ?

Comment: It's a temporary situation... I will buy a dedicated server in OVH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!SITE1/).*)$ /SITE1/$1 [L,NC]
```